# iFrame parser error after upgrading to .NET 4.8

Tags: .net, parsing, iframe, upgrade

I am trying to update an older web site from .NET 3.5 to 4.8. One issue I've come across relates to an iframe on an aspx page. The VS2022 project has a target framework of 4.8 as does the web.config file. The error on the page is:

The base class includes the field 'IFrame', but its type (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlIframe) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl).

In the aspx.designer.cs file, I can see that the declaration for the iFrame control appears correct:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlIframe IFrame;
```

I've already reviewed this post, and nothing in there worked for me:

[text](https://stackoverflow.com//questions/17809446/iframe-parser-error-after-upgrading-to-net-4-5%5D)

I tried manually updating the aspx.designer.cs file, changing the IFrame to HtmlGenericControl, as the error message indicates, but that didn't work. I wanted to try deleting the IFrame control and adding it back in via the Designer, but couldn't find an iFrame control in the toolbox, and wasn't sure if I could just do this via the .aspx file without causing further issues.

This was working initially after I did the .NET 4.8 update on the project, but I think I made some type of unknown change to the associated .aspx file, thate caused the aspx.designer.cs file to get updated, and think that's where the issue started.

I'm only relatively new to web code, so may be missing something obvious, but any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.